# Diffrence between websites and store

Tags: magento2, multistore, websites

what is the main difference between websites and store in magento2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually three things: A Website, a Store and a Store View.

**Websites**

You can set up as many websites as you need, and each can have a different domain.

**Stores**

A single website can have multiple stores—all are managed from the same Admin. Each store can have a different main menu, product selection, and appearance.

**Store Views**

Store views are usually used to present the store in different languages, although they can be used for other purposes, as well. Customers use the language chooser in the header to change the store view.

You can understand more by following
[image]

https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html

Answer (score 0):

**Websites :-**

It can be referred as the basis of the shop. Basically, you can think of a website as a domain/subdomain (though, this is perhaps an oversimplification). From one administration you can manage a few shops.

For different Magento websites it is possible to:

- to maintain a separate customer base, or can share the customer
  accounts within all websites.
- make different currencies.
- create
  different product pricing or make prices global (shared for all
  websites).

**Stores :-**

Stores are ‘children’ of websites.They are your actual product catalogue. Products and Categories are managed on the store level. A root category is configured for each store. They can be used to define for example different (looking) shops with the same information.

Managing stores it is worth to know:

- All the stores within one website share the same customer accounts.
- Currency and prices are identical for all the stores.
- Different shops can have different products assigned.

[image]